# C printf function specifier

Tags: c, printf, specifier

I need to print out a float value with 16 significant digits.

Right now when I print, it prints out

i.e 2.555556

when I want it to print out:  2.555555555555556 /// A total of 16 digits

My printf specifier currently is : "%20.18lf"

ideas?

Comment: You're aware that a float doesn't have 16 digits of precision?

Comment: I tried "%.16f" and it worked just fine for the number 1.0 / 3.0.

Comment: @Tibi: The expression `1.0 / 3.0` is of type `double`.

Answer (score 3):

If the value is of type `float`, you're probably not going to get more than about 7 significant digits after the decimal point.  If it's of type `double`, you can get about 15.  Depending on the system, `long double` may be no more precise than `double`; on mine, I get about 17 significant digits after the decimal point.

Most floating-point code uses type `double`; `float` is much less precise and often not significantly faster.

I'm a little surprised that you got `2.555556` rather than something like `2.555555582046508789` with a `"%20.18lf"` format.

Incidentally, the `l` (lowercase L) is not necessary.  The format for `double` is `"%f"`, and `float` arguments to `printf` are promoted to `double`, so `"%f"` is correct for both `float` and `double`.  The format for `long double` is `"%Lf"`.

Here's a test program I wrote:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void) {
    const float f        = 23.0/9.0;
    const double d       = 23.0/9.0;
    const long double ld = 23.0L/9.0L;
    printf("%20.18f\n%20.18f\n%20.18Lf\n", f, d, ld);
    return 0;
}
```

and the output I got on my system:

```
2.555555582046508789
2.555555555555555358
2.555555555555555556
```

Answer (score 0):

The following code works well (you have to enable C99 as `%lf` specifier is not part of earlier standards):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
        volatile float v = 2.555555555555556;
        printf("%20.18lf\n", v);
        return 0;
}
```

Prints the following:

```
$ gcc -std=c99 -Wall -pedantic -o test ./test.c 
$ ./test 
2.555555582046508789
$
```

If value is shorter, say 2.5, it right-pads it with zeros - `2.500000000000000000`.

So you have an error elsewhere. Generally, you have to post a minimal self-consistent code example that reproduces the problem. Otherwise you are on your own.

Comment: I figured out the problem guys. When I was inputting, I was using the same specifier for the input also, so it would crash

Answer (score 0):

C float or double is not precise enough, basically you need a high precision division function. Here is what I wrote. It is for integer division. You may need to revise it for float division.

```
int dividend=121, divisor=9;
int quotient,remainder;

//first print out the number before decimal point
quotient=dividend/divisor;
printf("%d", quotient);
remainder=dividend-quotient*divisor;

//print out decimal point
printf(".");

int digit_num=20;//this can be any precision you want

//second we calculate the number after decimal point
for(int i=0;i<digit_num;i++)
{
    remainder=remainder*10;
    quotient=remainder/divisor;
    remainder=remainder-quotient*divisor;
    printf("%d", quotient );
    dividend=remainder;
}

printf("\n");

printf("%d digits after decimal point has been printed out\n", digit_num );
```